# Why can't I restore dataset on pg admin with MacOS

Tags: postgresql, restore, pgadmin

With using sample dataset shared by `POSTGRESQL` Tutorial, I want to learn `SQL` but I can't restore my dataset. I created a database on `pgadmin`, I downloaded my dataset as zip and I unzip it but I can't choose the file that include my dataset. Also in windows when file unziped it appears as a `.tar` but in macbook it only a file.

I tried to restore file without unzipping it.

Comment: Use pg_restore or psql from the terminal, works much better and gives you a pretty clear error message when something is wrong. And please don't post images in your question, just plain text.

Comment: 1) The MacOS is showing the .tar file also, it just not including the extension.  2) Use [Restore Dialog](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/8.4/restore_dialog.html), select *Custom or tar* format, Then point at `dvdrental`